# Python with Selenium error: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm iniciant in Python with Selenium. Then, occur a error in my web scraping script; I would linke this community help me about this problem.

**Summary about script:**

- Acess this site:

https://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/simplesnacional/aplicacoes/atspo/pgmei.app/identificacao

- Input the EIN (**cnpj** in Brazil)
  [image]
- Click a link **"Emitir Guia de pagamento (DAS)"** this error occurs here
- Select a calendar year
- Click a **"ok"** button
- Enter the payment date for the DAS(s)
- Click a **"Apurar/Gerar Das"** button
  [image]

**Error:**

```
    Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"navbarCollapse > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2) > a"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.225); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
```

**Python with Selenium Code:** this cnpj is false

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
sleep(2)
driver.get("https://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/simplesnacional/aplicacoes/atspo/pgmei.app/identificacao")
sleep(2)


cnpj = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'cnpj')
cnpj.send_keys('00080303000111')


button_das = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'navbarCollapse > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2) > a')
button_das.click()
sleep(100)

select_calendar = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'anoCalendarioSelect')
select = Select(select_calendar)
select.select_by_value('2023')



button_calendar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > div > section:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > div > div > form > button')
button_calendar.click()
sleep(2)

dtpagamento= driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'dataPagamentoInformada')
dtpagamento.send_keys('24/01/2024')

button_gerarDas = driver.find_element(By.ID,'btnEmitirDas')
button_gerarDas.click()


sleep(50)
```

**Code 'Click a link **"Emitir Guia de pagamento (DAS)"'**

```
<section class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid bg-success">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATSPO/pgmei.app/Home/inicio"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Inicio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATSPO/pgmei.app/emissao"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" aria-hidden="true"></span> Emitir Guia de Pagamento (DAS)</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>

                                     Consulta Extrato/Pendências 
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="disabled">
                                            <a href="/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATSPO/pgmei.app/consulta/extrato" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="A opção Consulta Extrato/Pendências é habilitada apenas no PGMEI - versão completa, que exige controle de acesso." data-original-title="Acesso restrito"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Consulta Extrato</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="disabled">
                                            <a href="/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATSPO/pgmei.app/consulta/pendencia" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="A opção Consulta Extrato/Pendências é habilitada apenas no PGMEI - versão completa, que exige controle de acesso." data-original-title="Acesso restrito"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved" aria-hidden="true"></span> Consulta Pendência no Simei</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="disabled">
                                            <a href="/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATSPO/pgmei.app/consulta/dasEmitidos" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="A opção Consulta Extrato/Pendências é habilitada apenas no PGMEI - versão completa, que exige controle de acesso." data-original-title="Acesso restrito"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></span> Consulta DAS Emitidos</a>
                                        </li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" onclick="Utils.functions.abreAjudaManual();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ajuda</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATSPO/pgmei.app/home/sair"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sair</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.container -->
            </nav>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button_das = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'navbarCollapse > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2) > a')
```

Because `navbarCollapse` is an element id, you need to put a pound sign `#` in front of it.  Otherwise it interprets `navbarCollapse` as a tag name.

Comment: I did a test and put # in front of the navbarCollapse tag but the error continued